# Datetime Value Issue during time conversion

Tags: apex, datetime

I have executed following code on developer console and it shows incorrect hour. Since the time used is from Seattle (Pacific time) which is 8 hours behind GMT. So when datetime.hourGMT() is used shouldn't the value be converted to GMT time and then the hour component should be fetched. Please advise if i am missing something or how is the calculation done.

```
Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
DateTime SeattleTimeTest = DateTime.newInstance(System.Now().getTime() + tz.getOffset(System.Now()));
System.debug('Seattle Time ' +SeattleTimeTest+'-->'+SeattleTimeTest.hourGMT());
```

---

Output

```
Seattle Time 2020-01-23 14:41:29-->14
```

Answer (score 1):

Timezones are the bane of my existence, so I usually try to rationalize what is happening. Here is my result.

When you add your offset, apex will return a `datetime` record that will be identical to the time you have right now locally. However, as far as apex is concerned, that `datetime` will still be in GMT.

Hence, when you do `hourGMT`, you will get the exact hour you have in your `datetime` field. However, if you do `hour`, then apex will "translate" the time to your timezone.

In your case, `System.debug('Seattle hour ' + SeattleTimeTest.hour());` will return `6`, which would be Seattle local time when it is 14h in GMT.

The docs support this theory. For example, the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) for `newInstance(milliseconds)` say

> Constructs a Datetime and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.